# getting a file's access time in linux

Tags: linux, unix

Hello currently in linux I run stat with a file and it yields this:

```
File: `/var/www/html/assetlib/web/uploads/5d32500c44e62277d198a89d3ed8f69729d83e62.png'  
Size: 18241         Blocks: 40         IO Block: 4096   regular file                       
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 131903      Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (   48/  apache)   Gid: (   48/  apache)           
Access: 2013-06-04 05:33:08.909346476 +0000           
Modify: 2013-06-04 05:33:08.909346476 +0000                                             
Change: 2013-06-04 05:33:08.909346476 +0000\
```

how can I get the access time, I just want to be able to have 2013-06-04 05:33:08
I tried using awk but was unsuccessful, I am a noob at linux!
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: start with `man stat`... and check the `-c` or `--printf` args...

Answer (score 1):

`--printf='%x'` gives the last access time human readable (`man stat`). Then using `cut` to get rid of what comes after the `.`

```
$ stat --printf='%x' myfile | cut -d. -f 1
2013-06-02 16:00:15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
stat file | awk "NR==6"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test $ stat -c "%x" zsleep_cntr.sh
 2013-06-06 09:51:08.981417300 +0530
```

does this help ?

Answer (score 0):

Or using grep and cut:

```
stat backup.txt | grep Access | grep -v Uid | cut -b 9-37
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using awk:

```
stat myfile | awk '$1=="Access:" && NF==4 { gsub("\\..*$","",$3); print $2," ",$3 }'
```